# How to See What Processes are Running on Website

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I have a site/web-based application I'm working on and everything is running smoothly but recently when I've loaded up the pages (I use Google Chrome), the tab in the browser has the little 'loading' circle image that never ends. It's as if it's still loading the process and running something but nothing seems evident.

Nothing shows up in the developer console (error, warnings, etc.) and the actually speed of the page isn't affected when you click around. Also, there's no message at the bottom of the browser that says 'Resolving host...' or 'Loading www.example.com...', etc. I do have some AJAX going on on the site but not sure if that's the culprit.

Is there any way with developer tools to determine what processes are running on the page at the moment so I can begin to troubleshoot? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use fiddler tool to see what ajax requests are being generated and how much is time taken for every request.